# IISOle.MimeMapClass has no constructors

Tags: c#

I trying to use the `MimeMapClass` from IISOle.

I am getting the following error

```
The type 'IISOle.MimeMapClass' has no constructors defined
```

It happens when I try to instantiate the object

```
vRoot.Properties["MimeMap"].Add(new MimeMapClass { Extension = ext, MimeType = mime });
```

I get additional errors:

```
Interop type 'IISOle.MimeMapClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

'IISOle.MimeMapClass' does not contain a definition for 'Extension'
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: I updated the question with more information, thanks for your help

Comment: In your references tab are you embedding the interop types? If you are, try changing that to false.

Comment: Nice! Thanks pstrjds, that was it! I simply set the IISOle, Embed Interop Types to false and it compiled! Cheers. If add your suggestion as an answer I will mark it as the chosen answer. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is your issue as I don't know if you are using VS2010 or not. But if you are, try not embedding the interop types (see the properties of the reference you have added). According to this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx) it can cause you these type of troubles

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following? (Not production code - No error handling, disposing, or check for existing items provided.)

```
DirectoryEntry mimeMap = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/MimeMap")

PropertyValueCollection collection = mimeMap.Properties["MimeMap"];

MimeMapClass newMimeType = new MimeMapClass();
newMimeType.Extension = ext;
newMimeType.MimeType = mime;
collection.Add(newMimeType);
mimeMap.CommitChanges();
```